# RFI to RCE exploit

Tags: php, regex

My challenge is include php document by `$_GET['mPage']`.

below code: http://example.com/**includeMe.php**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

**moveTo.php** the regex:

```
if(preg_match("/(data|http|https|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/i", $_GET['mPage'])) {
echo 'no';
}
```

How can I bypass include `includeMe.php`?

tried:

http://example.com/moveTo.php?mPage=http://example.com/incldue.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that both php documents are accessible under the same domain, you can use "relative file access" and try something like this:

```
http://example.com/moveTo.php?mPage=includeMe.php
http://example.com/moveTo.php?mPage=../includeMe.php
```

Former worked for me if the files were in the same folder.
Depending on where the file is places in the file system you might need to traverse the file system using multiple `../` and correct folder names.

---

If "includeMe.php" is accessible under a different domain (e.g. example2.com), you need to use a protocol which is not included in the Regex.

As you can see here: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aW5dH4/2) all attempts using `http`, `https`, `data`, `ftp` are blocked. You can use `ftps` which is also very common in RFI.

A list with further possible evasions: https://websec.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/exploiting-php-file-inclusion-overview/

Comment: this is not working, its block protocols..
The file **includeMe.php** is no in same server

Comment: ok. thanks for the feedback. Did you try any other protocol or accessing your file using IP address instead of the domain (without protocol prefix). can you give me more information about the php `include` you want to exploit?